# Resize language selection dialog

Tags: installation, bitrock

Using Bitrock installer (now VMWare installer), is there a way to resize the language selection dialog?

There's some strings that are truncated in the title and I would love to be able to set a minimum size some how.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the whole dialog.

1. You can use these tags under

<project

```
        <height> 500</height>
        <width> 700</width>
```

2. You can also do the same by going to the Advanced tab > GUI > Look and feel and manually enter the size.
3. Or you can change the default string using custom.lang file

Comment: I don't think it would affect the language selection dialog though, and the main dialog is fine as it it.
How can you change the default string for the language selection dialog specifically? Could you give an example please?

Comment: @Nox You can simply edit the file, under your bitrock install builder installation directory this "C:\Program Files\VMware InstallBuilder Professional 20.3.0\docs\userguide\en.lng"

Making any changes in this file will be the default for every installer you create.

Or 

you can make a copy of the file in the same place where your XML file is. and Pass the path of the en.lng file into your XML file something like this ...
<customLanguageFileList>
   <language>
      <code>en</code>
      <file>path/to/custom-en.lng</file>
   </language>
</customLanguageFileList>

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look! I just wish I could resize any windows the way I want! But your workaround might work :)